# Converting pd.read_html list to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I need to find a table from Internet and in the following task, I need to filter that dataframe. However, `type` of the table becomes `list` if I use `pd.read_html` code. Therefore, I want to convert it to a dataframe. In an effort not to lose the column names in the table, I wrote the code that:

```
provincelist = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Turkish_provinces_by_GDP')
df = pd.DataFrame(provincelist, columns=["Rank", "Province", "GDP in mil. TRY (Nom)", 
                                        "GDP in mil. USD (PPP)", "Equivalent country[4]"])
df
```

However, I got an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1653                 blocks = [
-> 1654                     make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
   1655                 ]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype)
   3052 
-> 3053     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   3054 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
   2600 
-> 2601         super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   2602 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    123         if self._validate_ndim and self.ndim and len(self.mgr_locs) != len(self.values):
--> 124             raise ValueError(
    125                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 5

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-40df97d6adbe> in <module>
      1 provincelist = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Turkish_provinces_by_GDP')
----> 2 df = pd.DataFrame(provincelist, columns=["Rank", "Province", "GDP in mil. TRY (Nom)", 
      3                                         "GDP in mil. USD (PPP)", "Equivalent country[4]"])
      4 df

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    486                     mgr = arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    487                 else:
--> 488                     mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    489             else:
    490                 mgr = init_dict({}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    208         block_values = [values]
    209 
--> 210     return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
    211 
    212 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1662         blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]
   1663         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1664         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   1665 
   1666 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   1692     if block_shape[0] == 0:
   1693         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
-> 1694     raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
   1695 
   1696 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 5)
```

How can I handle that problem?

Thank you for your help already!

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.read_html()` returns a list of `DataFrames` as stated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).

I have tried your code and you probably want to pick the first item from `provincelist`:

```py
provincelist = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Turkish_provinces_by_GDP')
provinceDf = provincelist[0]

print(type(provinceDf))
print(provinceDf)
```

If this is not what you want, you probably want to inspect each item in `provincelist` using `print()` and `type()`